# Meteor weak dependency not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've tried to add a weak dependency to my package. But it doesnt seem to be working. Here is the repo https://github.com/arunhedcet/meteor-weak-dependency-test

[package.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arunhedcet/meteor-weak-dependency-test/master/packages/weak-test/package.js)

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Test of Meteor's weak dependency resolution"
})

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.use('iron:router', ['client', 'server'], {weak: true})

  api.add_files('weak-test.js', 'server')
})
```

[weak-test.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arunhedcet/meteor-weak-dependency-test/master/packages/weak-test/weak-test.js)

```
var router = Package['iron_router'];

console.log("[weak-test] iron-router package found?", !!router);
console.log(router);
```

Looks like it is working fine in these cases

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/dc3cd6eb92f2bdd1bb44000cdd6abd1e5d0285b1/packages/facts

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/dc3cd6eb92f2bdd1bb44000cdd6abd1e5d0285b1/packages/markdown

I'm not able to find out what the error is.

Comment: Doesn't weak means that it can be loaded _after_ your package and thus not be available when your code executes?

Comment: @Kyll. Check this https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2524 .